# Add a text field to the Form Header in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm new to using MS Access.  I'm working on a legacy system which has many preexisting forms and reports.  The industry I work in requires the date and time to be affixed to all reports when printed to meet regulatory guidelines.  I can add the following code in a Text box:

```
="Generated from ACME Consumables live database on " & Date() & " at " & Time()
```

to Report Headers and I get the expected result when the report is printed.  However if I add it to a Form Header the Text box is empty when the form is printed.  I'm stuck on this simple task and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Works fine here. But forms aren't really for print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention if it works on screen or not, only when printed. If it works on screen then make sure `Display When` property is not set to `Screen Only`.